# React js give me a unknown warning, I cant fix it,

Tags: reactjs

I use React for frontend, I am facing a warning in React. I tried a lot but couldn't get rid of it.

warning : react_devtools_backend.js:3973 Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillMount in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate bugs in your code. See https://reactjs.org/link/unsafe-component-lifecycles for details.

- Move code with side effects to componentDidMount, and set initial state in the constructor.

Comment: As the error message says: You or some of your libraries (node_modules) used `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` function and it is unsafe.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.